# Is there a minimum $\beta$ such that $\alpha\in \mathrm{V}_\beta$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Given some ordinal $\alpha$, is it known whether or not there is a minimum $\beta$ such that $\alpha\in\mathrm{V}_\beta$?

If so, then what is it? I've nailed it down for a couple ordinals:

$\omega:\omega+1$. This is because $\mathrm{V}_\omega$ does not contain $\omega$ (it is not hereditarily finite), but it is a set of hereditarily finite sets ($0,1,2,3,4...$), so $\mathrm{V}_{\omega+1} $ does.
$\omega+1:\omega+2$. This is because $\omega+1$ is not a set of hereditarily finite sets, (it contains $\omega$), but it is a set of sets of hereditarily finite sets. 
This pattern of $\omega+\alpha:\omega+\alpha+1$ continues for all finite $\alpha$, but does it continue beyond $\omega\cdot2$? What about $\omega^2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you see a pattern like this in the ordinals, the best thing to do is to see if transfinite induction can help: supposing that the pattern holds up to $\gamma$, can you show that it continues to hold at $\gamma$? At the same time, just like with normal induction, [it's sometimes easier to prove a seemingly *more ambitious* statement](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31699/strengthening-the-induction-hypothesis).

In this case, try to prove the following:

> $(*)\quad$ If $\alpha$ is an ordinal, then the ordinals in $V_\alpha$ are exactly those $<\alpha$.

*(In symbols: "$Ord\cap V_\alpha=\alpha$." Remember that "$Ord$" denotes the class of ordinals itself, and an ordinal is exactly the set of ordinals smaller than itself.)*

COMMENTS:

- Note that $(*)$ implies that for every ordinal $\alpha$, the first $\beta$ for which we have $V_\beta\ni\alpha$ is $\beta=\alpha+1$. So if you can prove $(*)$ you've answered your question.
- To get things started, $(*)$ is trivially true for $\alpha=0$: there are no ordinals $<0$, and there are no elements of $V_0$.
- For a limit ordinal $\lambda$, note that $Ord\cap V_{\lambda}=\bigcup_{\gamma<\lambda}(Ord\cap V_\gamma)$; do you see how to use this to show that if $(*)$ holds up to $\lambda$, it holds at $\lambda$ too?
- Finally, for the successor step: do you see how to show that if $Ord\cap V_\alpha=\alpha$, then $Ord\cap V_{\alpha+1}=\alpha+1=\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$? This has two parts: first, show that $Ord\cap V_{\alpha+1}$ is *at least as big as* $\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$, and secondly, showing that it is *no bigger than* $\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$; try tackling each part separately, and remember how $V_{\alpha+1}$ is defined.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to use transfinite induction, but I got stuck. This solves the problem!

Comment: @Zetapology Glad to help!